# How to stop an element in JavaScript at the screen border?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am beginner in JavaScript and I'm trying to create a simple game. I'm looking for a way to stop the rectangle when it touches the screen border by stopping `setInterval()`, I can't get the value of the left screen border.

```js
const element = document.querySelector('#rectangle');
let a = 1;
document.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
    switch (e.keyCode) {
        case 37:
            let leftInterval = setInterval(moveLeft, 100);
            break;
        case 39:
            let rightInterval = setInterval(moveRight, 100);
            break;
    }
});
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    rectangle.style.position = 'absolute';
    rectangle.style.left = "44%";
});
let moveLeft = () => {
    element.style.left = parseInt(element.style.left) - a + '%';
}
let moveRight = () => {
    element.style.left = parseInt(element.style.left) + a + '%';
}
function clearinterval() {
    if (element.style.left < 0)
        clearinterval(leftInterval);
}
clearinterval();
```

```css
body {
    background-color: brown;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#rectangle {
    bottom: 2.5%;
    background-color: burlywood;
    width: 12%;
    height: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div id="rectangle"></div>
```

Comment: Please add the HTML to create a working [mre]!

Comment: You never cancel the original intervals so if i press left, left, right there are 3 intervals each doing their own thing. Perhaps have a single interval that is cancelled each time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will help you.

```js
const element = document.querySelector('#rectangle');
let a = 1;
document.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
    switch (e.keyCode) {
        case 37:
            let leftInterval = setInterval(moveLeft, 100);
            break;
        case 39:
            let rightInterval = setInterval(moveRight, 100);
            break;
    }
});
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    rectangle.style.position = 'absolute';
    rectangle.style.left = "44%";
});
let moveLeft = () => {
    if (parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(element,null).getPropertyValue("left")) > 10) {
        element.style.left = parseInt(element.style.left) - a + '%';
    }
}
let moveRight = () => {
    if (parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(element,null).getPropertyValue("right")) > 10) {
    element.style.left = parseInt(element.style.left) + a + '%';
    }
}
// function clearinterval() {
    
//         // clearinterval(leftinterval);
// }

// clearinterval();
```